# Мигание при новом сообщении (Delphi, VCL)

Tags: delphi, chat, vcl

Я пишу чат на Delphi по схеме клиент <-> сервер <-> клиент.
Задача в следующем: нужно заставить приложение мигать, когда **оно свернуто и есть новое сообщение**, и только в этом случае.
Проблема же: приложение не моргает. Ни в том, ни в другом случае.
Вот код (Получение нового сообщения и включение таймера моргания (minimized - это глобальная переменная, главная операция с которой в Timer4)

```
procedure TForm2.ClientSocket1Read(Sender: TObject; Socket: TCustomWinSocket);
begin
  if minimized = 0 then
    Timer3.Enabled := False
  else
    Timer3.Enabled := True;
  
  Listbox1.Items.Add(Socket.ReceiveText);
end;
```

Timer3:

```
procedure TForm2.Timer3Timer(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if minimized = 0 then
    Timer3.Enabled := False;

  FlashWindow(Handle, True); 
  FlashWindow(Application.Handle, True);
end;
```

Timer4:

```
procedure TForm2.Timer4Timer(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if IsIconic(Application.Handle) then
    minimized := 1
  else
    minimized := 0;
end;
```

Comment: Возможно, вы просто не замечаете **однократного** мигания. Попробуйте воспользоваться FlashWindowEx. Кроме того, использовать мигание сразу для двух окон - нежелательно. Анализируйте свойство `Application.MainFormOnTaskbar` и в зависимости от этого вызывайте мигание или Form2.Handle или Application.Handle.

Comment: Дополнение: таймер 4 - излишен. Проверку, осуществляемую в нем элементарно можно осуществить в таймере 3 и обойтись без глобальной переменной.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для мигания окна в панели задач есть спец. функция - [FlashWindowEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679347%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Так же можно воспроизводить звук, мигать иконкой в системном трее, всплывающее окошко с сообщением и т.д..